# JQuery-JTable stretching in IE7 - OK in other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, jquery-jtable

The JQuery-JTable plugin has some issues with IE7. As the author has already stated on [this](https://github.com/hikalkan/jtable/issues/124) thread, there's not much support for IE7.

Therefore, I have this problem:

When I have, for example, a description field (usually a textarea), in IE7 it will stretch the div, making the JTable look enourmous. Like this:

[image: In IE7]

In every other browser (tested in Chrome, Firefox and IE 8-9), it doesn't happen:

[image: other browsers]

This is the JTable fields binding:

```
fields: {
                code: {
                    title: 'CND',
                    key: true,
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list: false
                },
                company: {
                    title: 'company',
                    list: true,
                    create: true,
                    edit: true
                },
                cert: {
                    title: 'cert',
                    edit: true,
                    create: true
                },
                emission: {
                    title: 'emission'                    
                },
                descriptions: {
                    title: 'descriptions',
                    type: 'textarea',
                    edit: true,
                    list: true,
                    create: true,
                    maxWidth: '100px',
                    showHint: true
            }
```

Has anyone ever been through this kind of a problem?
I guess I can just tell the user to use Firefox or Chrome, but I want to give this a shot first.